# Couldn't retrieve the graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my activity_main.xml.
when I try to switch to the graphical view, it says Pick a fragment from the "Fragment Layout" menu.

Plus, neither the button nor the spinner shows up in my layout !!!!!

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  />

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_find"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spr_place_type"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spr_place_type"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

I've posted this before yet couldn't solve the problem ...Can anyone solve this problem for me ?

Comment: I think previewing the GoogleMaps is not possible at all. Why don't you try to run it instead to view it live?

Comment: I tried your code it's working fine ... ;)

Comment: ... **cudnt**?? **rilly**??

Comment: @FrankN.Stein that means couldn't ... :P

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this all the items are displayed fine try it and then set them according to your needs..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_find"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
  android:text="@string/str_btn_find" />

<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spr_place_type"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/btn_find" />

 <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/spr_place_type"
  android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```